# MongoDb query for sorting the document by value

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting, object

This is data for collection 'Topic'

```
{
 _id: 'abcd1',
 viewers: ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']
}
{
 _id: 'abcd2',
 viewers: ['user1', 'user3']
}
{
 _id: 'abcd3',
 viewers: ['user1']
}
```

For instance, suppose current logged user is `user2`. I want to sort in this way that `unread` topics for `user2` come first. I.e. i want to ensure that whether the `user2` has viewed this topic or not. If not it should come first in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the query to sort the result based on whether the "user" has viewed it. The viewed stuff comes last.

**"viewed_page" attribute in the output will have:-**

1) false - if not already viewed

2) true - if already viewed

**Query:-**

Please change the first array inside setIsSubset accordingly. The first array is the input parameter.

```
db.viewers.aggregate(
   [
      {
         $project:
           {
             _id: 1,
             viewers: 1,  
             viewed_page:               
                 { $setIsSubset: [ ["user3"], {$ifNull: [ "$viewers", [""] ]} ] }

           }
      },
      {$sort : { viewed_page : 1 } }
   ]
);
```

**Output for user2:-**

```
{
    "_id" : "abcd2",
    "viewers" : [ 
        "user1", 
        "user3"
    ],
    "viewed_page" : false
}

{
    "_id" : "abcd3",
    "viewers" : [ 
        "user1"
    ],
    "viewed_page" : false
}

{
    "_id" : "abcd1",
    "viewers" : [ 
        "user1", 
        "user2", 
        "user3"
    ],
    "viewed_page" : true
}
```

**Output for user3:-**

```
{
    "_id" : "abcd3",
    "viewers" : [ 
        "user1"
    ],
    "viewed_page" : false
}

{
    "_id" : "abcd1",
    "viewers" : [ 
        "user1", 
        "user2", 
        "user3"
    ],
    "viewed_page" : true
}

{
    "_id" : "abcd2",
    "viewers" : [ 
        "user1", 
        "user3"
    ],
    "viewed_page" : true
}
```

**Output for user1:-**

All three documents have user1, so I have not included the output for "user1".

> $setIsSubset Takes two arrays and returns true when the first array is
>   a subset of the second, including when the first array equals the
>   second array, and false otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for answer but it's throwing error.
`assert: command failed: {
 "errmsg" : "exception: both operands of $setIsSubset must be arrays. Second argument is of type: EOO",
 "code" : 17042,
 "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed`

Comment: Also tell what if i want to project all the keys with it without explicitly selecting?

Comment: Updated my answer to handle empty array object and viewers attribute not present documents. This should solve the EOO error.

Comment: Great! But let me know about projecting all the keys in the document. Because there are too much keys so it would not be good to explicitly setting 1 to each keys.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to include the fields by default. You have to explicitly include all the fields.